# Comparing variadic templates

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

If I have two variadic template arguments, `A` and `B`, how can I ensure at compile-time that the types of all of the members of  `A` are also the types of a subset of `B` (in the same order)?

Contrived example:

```
template<typename...A>
struct Foo {
  template<typename...B>
  static void bar()
  {
  }
}

...

Foo<Apple, Orange>:: template bar<Apple, Orange, Grape>(); // this compiles
Foo<Apple, Orange>:: template bar<Orange, Grape>(); // this doesn't
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For a general subset I don't know, but if you can guarantee that `B` is of the form `A..., More...`, then this may do:

```
#include <functional>
#include <tuple>

template <typename ...A>
struct var_equal : std::false_type { };

template <typename A1, typename ...Aother, typename B1, typename ...Bother>
struct var_equal<std::tuple<A1, Aother...>, std::tuple<B1, Bother...>>
{
  static const bool value = std::is_same<A1, B1>::value && var_equal<std::tuple<Aother...>, std::tuple<Bother...>>::value;
};

template <typename ...B>
struct var_equal<std::tuple<>, std::tuple<B...>> : std::true_type { };


template<typename...A>
struct Foo {
  template<typename...B>
  static void bar()
  {
    static_assert(var_equal<std::tuple<A...>, std::tuple<B...>>::value, "Hello");
  }
};
```

(Sorry, `var_equal` is a terrible name. It should be called something more appropriate, like `initial_equal`.)

---

**Update:** Here is the general solution, worked out in detail by **Luc Danton** ([see here](http://ideone.com/vvLI4) for his beautifully styled code):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

template <typename Sub, typename Super>
struct subset_of : std::false_type {};

template<typename Same, typename... AOther, typename... BOther>
struct subset_of<std::tuple<Same, AOther...>, std::tuple<Same, BOther...>>
: subset_of<
    std::tuple<AOther...>
    , std::tuple<BOther...>
> {};

template<typename ADifferent, typename BDifferent, typename... AOther, typename... BOther>
struct subset_of<std::tuple<ADifferent, AOther...>, std::tuple<BDifferent, BOther...>>
: subset_of<
    std::tuple<ADifferent, AOther...>
    , std::tuple<BOther...>
> {};

template<typename... B>
struct subset_of<std::tuple<>, std::tuple<B...>>: std::true_type {};

template<typename... A>
struct Foo {
    template<typename... B>
    static void bar()
    {
        static_assert(subset_of<std::tuple<A...>, std::tuple<B...>>::value, "Hello");
    }
};
```

Test case:

```
struct Apple{}; struct Orange{}; struct Grape{};

int main()
{
    Foo<Apple, Orange>::bar<Apple, Orange, Grape>();               // this compiles
    Foo<Apple, Orange>::bar<Grape, Apple, Grape, Orange, Grape>(); // this also compiles
    Foo<Apple, Orange>::bar<Orange, Grape>();                      // this doesn't
}
```

Comment: So you are using recursion to check whether A is prefix of B. That can be easily extended to implement sublist check. Using more concise syntax for the general algorithm it would be `is_sublist A, B1:Brest = var_equal(A, B1:Brest) || is_sublist(A, Brest)`, i.e. A is sublist of B if it's prefix of it, or a sublist of B without first element. Rewriting in C++ should be straightforward.

Comment: I think reasonable name for `var_equal` would be `is_prefix`, because it's checking whether A is prefix of B.

Comment: Wait for it, Luc is proposing to make this infinitely more powerful... Using `is_same` was a silly idea in any case :-)

Comment: @Kerrek: now the real challenge, and what if the order is not guaranteed ? I have an obvious O(N^2) solution, but wonder if we could somehow "sort" the types (I seem to recall that the MPL managed it).

Comment: Haha. (Yes. That's my reply. Do feel free to post your solution, I'll upvote you!)

Comment: More seriously: Eventually it becomes questionable what the utility of such a comparison would be. I imagine we somehow have to make reference to objects of those types at some point, so reordering the arguments would seem to get in the way of that... unless you really just want this for its own sake. Maybe implement some compile-time travelling salesman?

Comment: @Kerrek: actually, I am more interested in pure compile-time checks. Typically, think of a simple SQL queries: `select a, b from table`, you need to check that both `a` and `b` are columns of `table`, otherwise the request is meaningless.

Comment: @Kerrek: reading further on Boost.MPL, the Associative sequence concept does not produce an ordered relationship, I don't think it is possible then (generally speaking) without associating a numeric key to each tag.

Comment: I actually wanted the first solution specifically, but it's really neat to see both! Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @Sydius - it was fun! The first solution can also be simplified, you can get rid of `std::is_same` and just make the two template parameters `A1` and `B1` the same.